# How to dynamically append unknown number of div elements to your svg

Tags: d3.js

I need to append a number of div elements based on the result of calling my db, and inside those div elements append other elements.
For example, I get back 10 rows, so I have to append 10 texts and 10 lines (the divs) on each of which I am appending some circles based on the data for each row. Since the number of circles is unbounded, I was thinking of appending a scrollable div.

Now that I have done this, the elements are appended with the right attributes (according to developer tools), but one cannot see them on the page!

Is there a way to dynamically append divs so that the elements within them are visible?

Comment: Yes -- if you share your code/results we can help you with the specific problem.

Comment: Thanks Lars. The problem is really simple. I have attached a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6ob7auoz/1/

As you can see, the code, as is forked from another jsfiddle, is working fine. Now if you append a parent div, the elements still exist on the page, but does not show.

This happens any time one appends a number of div elements dynamically and try to append elements within.

Why I needs this to have is that I need to have a scrollable div in which a dynamic number of elements are going to be appended.

Comment: You can't have `div`s inside `svg`s. Use `g` elements instead http://jsfiddle.net/6ob7auoz/3/

Comment: The issue, as mentioned above is that I need s scrollable element, such as a div or a span, with a fixed width. One cannot apply that to a g element.

Also, there are many of such elements to be appended inside a parent g, and I already have that part.

Comment: Ok, then use an HTML container instead of SVG.

Comment: I simply cannot.
All my code pieces are d3 and related to one another.

Comment: Well, you could also try using a `foreignObject` element with the `div` inside it.

Comment: Could you please apply this to the jsfiddle?

Comment: This won't work in your jsfiddle because you have SVG elements inside the `div` again but not HTML elements.

Comment: So to make sure, none of these orders won't work:

svg --> g --> div (scrollable) --> d3 rect & text

svg --> g --> foreignObject --> div (scrollable) --> d3 rect & text

Comment: It would be by doing something like `svg > g > foreignObject > body > div > svg > g (> rect) (> foreignObject > body > div > svg)` but this would be really convoluted.

Comment: So you too see no work around to make the elements within a duynamically appended div visible.
I trie this latter sequence you mentioned and that also didn't work.

Comment: No, there is a way to make this work, but you're making this much more difficult than it actually is. If you simply set the size of the SVG accordingly to accommodate all content, it should work.

Comment: Pardon me if this is becoming a silly back and forth, but I really cannot see how this can be fixed with svg size manipulation.
Let me redraw the scene for you, so that maybe we build a common ground here:

I have a main svg, in which I have 2 different main g elements. In one of the groups, I will have a set of circles and for each circle, an axis that will show the elements for that circle, e.g. a document and its topics. Now to append the topics, I need a scrollable div so that for docs with #topics>3, the div scroll instead of document topics grow into the other g element.

Comment: So you could have a `div` at the top level instead of an SVG element right? You can do what you want with various nested `foreignObject` elements, but the code would be horrible. Breaking up the individual elements into separate SVGs and positioning them in HTML will make it much easier.